# How to custom embed Soundcloud track?

Tags: html, embed, soundcloud

Is it possible to embed a Soundcloud track with only a custom play and pause button and the title of the song?

Look out for some advice.
Casper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the widget api, you can bind method to play pause .... https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods

And with css you can still hide the widget.

Other option is using the api https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing

> Streaming Sounds Note if you are going to stream from our API you need
> to attribute properly. Make sure you've read our Terms and Attribution
> Guidelines to make sure you treat our creators content correctly. When
> using a custom player you must:
>
> - Credit the uploader as the creator of the sound
> - Credit SoundCloud as the source by including one of the logos
> - Link to the SoundCloud URL containing the work
> - If the sound is private link to the profile of the creator
>
> If you don't want to use the SoundCloud widget,
> our API gives you the ability to access a sound's stream URL and use
> your own player to play sounds from SoundCloud.